# Does everything that has CSS attached in BEM need a class name?

Tags: css, less, bem

As people are still advising to use BEM for larger projects I thought I might give it a shot. But I already run into a problem by setting up the `header`-element of the page.

---

This is how the page's header looks now:

```
<header class="header">
    <img class="header__logo" src="logo.png" alt="alt">

    <button class="header__button-toggle" type="button">Open menu</button>

    <nav class="header__nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Nav item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I understand how to define simple elements, like `header__logo` or `header__button-toggle`.

---

However I'm not sure what to do, when it comes to the `nav`-element. The HTML is not going to change, as this is a common and well approved pattern and will be the same in 5 years, I guess.

Now I need to apply styles not only to the `nav`-element but also to the `ul`, the `li` and the `a`-elements as well. How do I do this?

I would do it like this in Less:

```
.header {
    &__nav {
        property: value;

        ul { property: value; }
        li { property: value; }
        a { property: value; }
    }
}
```

But is this valid in BEM or is this what BEM wants to eliminate?

---

Must I end up with something like this instead?

```
.header {
    &__nav {
        property: value;

        &__list { property: value; }
        &__item { property: value; }
        &__anchor { property: value; }
    }
}
```

Which clutters the HTML extremely:

```
<nav class="header__nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="header__nav__list">
        <li class="header__nav__item">
            <a class="header__nav__anchor" href="">Nav item A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__nav__item">
            <a class="header__nav__anchor" href="">Nav item B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__nav__item">
            <a class="header__nav__anchor" href="">Nav item C</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Maybe someine can help me understand, how this would be solved correctly in terms of BEM.

Comment: Just throwing this out here: http://getbem.com/faq/#ask-your-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should assign a class to each element you need to address in CSS (see: https://en.bem.info/methodology/html/#binding-blocks-to-a-dom-node). And you should not be afraid of extra bytes in your markup as gzip will compress it just fine.

But you should avoid elements of the elements (please refer to: https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-create-elements-of-elements-block__elem1__elem2 for reasoning).

So proper markup will be like this:

```
<nav class="header__nav nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__anchor" href="">Nav item A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__anchor" href="">Nav item B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__anchor" href="">Nav item C</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You may also noticed that there are two different classes on `nav` element. That's called `mix` in BEM methodology: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful and makes some other points clear, especially how to handle nested elements and these *mixes*. Even though every element has a class now, it looks more readable then my first approach using `header_nav_list`. I think sometimes the official BEM docs have too simplified "textbook examples". Thanks again.